# Keep part of string after last sign.

Tags: r

I would like to keep only the string after the last `|` sign in my rownames which looks like this: 
in:

```
"d__Bacteria|p__Proteobacteria|c__Gammaproteobacteria|o__Chromatiales|f__Woeseiaceae|g__Woeseia"
```

out:

```
g__Woeseia
```

I have this code which keeps everything from the start until a given sign:

```
gsub("^.*\\.",".",x)
```

Answer (score 2):

We could do this by capturing as a group.  Using `sub`, match characters (`.*`) until the `|` and capture zero or more characters that are not a `|` (`([^|]*)`) until the end (`$`) of the string and replace by the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub(".*\\|([^|]*)$", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "g__Woeseia"
```

---

Or match characters until the `|` and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub(".*\\|", "", str1)
#[1] "g__Woeseia"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "d__Bacteria|p__Proteobacteria|c__Gammaproteobacteria|o__Chromatiales|f__Woeseiaceae|g__Woeseia"
```